# Validate relation one to one EF and data-annotations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation, data-annotations

I have a class Article that has a 1 to 1 relation with Category. I'm using validation with data annotations to show error messages to the user.

this is my Article MetaData:

```
 public class ArticuloMetaData
    {
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public String Name { get; set; }

        public int IdCategory{ get; set; } 

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }
```

In the Create Article form I got a dropdownlist populated with a List of Categories and an "empty" Category "Choose One" with id = 0

What is the best practice to check the required relation asuming that 0 is an incorrect value because fk constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could decorate your IdCategory like so:

```
[Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
public int IdCategory{ get; set; }
```

This will help you validate "non-empty" categories.